# .factory must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: angularjs

please help me what mistake im doing Here

**factory.js**

```
angular.module('MyApp').factory('MilkFactory', function ($http) {
    var GeneralService = {};
    GeneralService.DoCal = function () {
        return $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:10948/Api/Home/GetEmployee',
            method: 'Get',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

**EmpCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('EmployeeController', function ($scope, EmployeeService, $q, MilkFactory) {
$scope.GetFactory = function () {
        MilkFactory.DoCal().then(function () {
            alert('Milk is calling...')
            return 
        })
    }
```

Comment: Side note: don't call your service "MilkFactory". Call it "milkService". The factory is the callback function passed to factory(). The service, which is injected in controllers and other services, is the object created and returned by this factory callback function.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you soo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the service object from the factory

```
angular.module('MyApp').factory('MilkFactory', function ($http) {
    var generalService = {};
    generalService.DoCal = function () {
        return $http({...});
     };
     return generalService;
 });
```